# Facing issue with python - report lab. Unable to get header & footer on every page?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf-generation, reportlab

As the title states, im using python's reportlab library to generate pdf. I have generate header & footer in it & it visible but when I'm trying to get the same header & footer on every page. I'm unable to do it

I have tried partial update & on page callback but nothing seems to help

I have tried partial update & on page callback but nothing seems to help

Also tried creating another template but that didn't help neither

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.